# The development server returned response error code :500

Tags: android, react-native

I have just created a React Native application in **Webstorm** , but when i run it,  it shows this error :

```
The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false

Body:
{"message":"TransformError: F:\\MyApps\\CatalogueApp\\index.android.js: Unexpected token ) (While processing preset: \"F:\\\\MyApps\\\\CatalogueApp\\\\node_modules\\\\babel-preset-react-native\\\\index.js\")","type":"TransformError","lineNumber":0,"description":"","errors":[{"description":"","lineNumber":0}]}
processBundleResult
    BundleDownloader.java:170
access$100
    BundleDownloader.java:39
onResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:139
execute
    RealCall.java:135
run
    NamedRunnable.java:32
runWorker
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113
run
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588
run
    Thread.java:818
```

Why ?

Below is the image :

[image]

Comment: It's in the message... `Unexpected token )`

Comment: What do you mean @cricket_007? ,

Comment: `native\\\\index.js\")"`... That's invalid JSON

Comment: Ok , now how can i change it , and to what ?

Comment: I'm just pointing out the error. I don't know where that data is processed. I assumed you'd be able to do a project wide search in your IDE

Comment: oooh man , i tried to look at the project but still don't know how to knock it out

Comment: Well, start by adding your `index.android` files, or anything that references them to your question

Comment: Well , i got the answer @cricket_007i uninstalled  **babel-preset-react-native**

Answer (score 3):

**This is what i did in the command prompt** It helped me.

```
npm uninstall babel-preset-react-native
npm install babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0
```

It means the new version of `babel-preset-react-native` library and there is an unsupported trailing commas on that new version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It resolved by correcting the code. Take a look at the node window that has opened when you ran "`react-native run-android`", It's reporting where's the problem, for example it reports:

> Unexpected token (27:6)

and then it reports a part of your code that is making the error. Open up the `App.js` file, review the code part that has made the problem and correct it.

Take a look at the below picture and pay attention to the yellow part.

[image]